# Table borders in IE (8,9 & 10) not showing

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

I have a table and I want horizontal borders on the rows, this works fine in *real browsers* but in IE it just doesn't show, here is my CSS and an image of what is happening.  How can I fix this?

**Screenshot**

[image]

**CSS**

```
.defaultTableStyle {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100%;
}

    .defaultTableStyle th {
        background: #eee;
    }

    .defaultTableStyle th, .defaultTableStyle td {
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 6px 8px;
        position: relative;
        text-align: left;
        vertical-align: top;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
    <table class="defaultTableStyle" id="resultsTable">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Success Rate</th>
            <th>Coverage</th>
            <th>Duration</th>
        </tr>
            <tr style="" data-result-id="3362" data-successrate="100" data-coverage="2" class="resultDataContainer">
                <td><span class=""><i class="icon-ok"></i></span></td>
                <td>27/02/2014 09:16:29</td>
                <td>100%</td>
                <td>2%</td>
                <td>1 sec</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="" data-result-id="3361" data-successrate="100" data-coverage="2" class="resultDataContainer">
                <td><span class=""><i class="icon-ok"></i></span></td>
                <td>27/02/2014 09:15:28</td>
                <td>100%</td>
                <td>2%</td>
                <td>1 sec</td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Does is still do it if you apply the border to both top *and* bottom?

Comment: @Timmah I get one extra border at the bottom, but not on all rows!

Comment: Can you paste some of the table HTML?

Comment: Do you have IE's zoom setting zoomed out?

Comment: maybe because of `border-collapse: collapse;`..

Comment: can you provide the actual HTML which show in screenshot

Comment: i think you have not added border to the bottom http://jsfiddle.net/HarishBoke/3fRub/

Comment: @Harish The fiddle looks correct, if I copy your CSS exactly it renders the same on my screen! WTF?! lol

Comment: @DavidOliver No the zoom is at 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest removing `position:relative`, in part because it doesn't do anything for a cell and in part from pure IE-fear (it does weird things with positioning).

In addition to that, try Binita's answer. Instead of two shorthand declarations, though, try:

```
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-width: 1px 0;
```

Comment: I did actually try the long hand version to no avail... amazingly though it was the `position: relative;` screwing stuff up, thanks!

Comment: Also you should apply the border styling at the `<tr>` row level to avoid the repeat for each cell, with improved performance.

Comment: Styling TRs can have unstable results, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Should work with adding border-bottom as well with the existing css

```
.defaultTableStyle th, .defaultTableStyle td {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So here you go add `border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;` to the TD jsfiddle.net/HarishBoke/3fRub

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

```
<table cellspacing="0" and cellpadding="0"> ... </table>
```

From [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/c674a015-11cb-49af-a876-887fe7900d89/ie9-css-table-with-bordercollapse-fails-to-render-some-borders-when-printing?forum=iewebdevelopment).

Answer (score 0):

Check if your IE Zoom is set to 100%. Spent time searching for a solution when I noticed that I am working on 80% zoom. 
Only now as I type this answer I found the comment above pointing to this issue.